# How to implement SSO with Oauth between two websites?

Tags: authentication, oauth, single-sign-on

I need to share the same authentication database for two different websites, the process would be:

1. User visit http://firstsite.com
2. Login to this firstsite domain
3. The page redirects to http://secondsite.com
4. User is already authenticated into the new site

The authentication may use server-to-server connection to share the authentication data, but my question is how can I handle the user redirect to keep the authentication switching page and domain?

What is the most common way to share an already authenticated session? Is it safe to use a queryparam on the redirect URL? maybe the Oauth token?

Comment: OAuth2 is indeed a technology thats used for this.

Comment: Thanks for confirming I'm on the right way. But how you would share/pass the access token between different sites during redirect?

Comment: The OAuth2 process tells you *exactly* how. This is a good place to start reading: https://oauth.net/ . The specific grant_type you'll likely want is `authorization_code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, OAuth is what you're after, if you want a standards-based solution. You will have one Authorization Server under a separate domain, e.g. https://login-for-my-sites.example.com Then, `firstsite` and `secondsite` will be clients of that OAuth server. Each can start a code flow to get an access token. The server is then responsible for authenticating the user. As this is the same server, the user will only have to authenticate once. Her session will be kept on the device, and she will be automatically authenticated during subsequent OAuth flows.

Comment: Thanks Michal, but I still have a doubt. The login (user/passw fields) have to be handled by the firstsite.com, the backend server of firstsite will receive the post call and forward the request to the auth server. With this configuration, firstsite clearly can get all passwords. Maybe is not possibile to do in a different way if it is mandatory to keep the login process in the firstsite domain, but I would like to be sure about it.

Comment: The passwords belong to the authorization server. If there is a requirement that login is handled by firstsite.com, then this site must implement the functionality of an authorization server (or deploy a server under e.g. login.firstsite.com or firstsite.com/login). Then secondsite.com can start an authorization flow with firststite.com